# We are unable to login to our wordpress screecast attached

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

We ran into issue we are non technilcal with very less knowlege of Wordpress. When we try login to wordpress it redirects us and the login didn't work. Check out the screencast.
This issue is for all user, are we hacked?

https://app.birdeatsbug.com/sessions/3-Rj-IAAo-N8xTb4CZwUd74cornxl-i0Ysb8Ah2Hkfk7

I tried login and we are unable to login

Comment: did the login stopped working all of a sudden? I mean, it was working correctly before today?

Comment: @GrafiCode Yes it was working perfectly until last night when we checked, we had multiple users

Comment: what if you try to login from this url (no redirects): https://executivesdiary.com/blog/wp-login.php

Comment: I see it's giving 404 even in login page... not sure what's happening, but we definitely have not enough info su support you

Comment: @GrafiCode I sort the issue when I login with VPN, it's not happening on my Ip for another user who is not on my IP they are also able to login, what's the root cause of this.

Comment: do you have some security plugin installed on wordpress? maybe your IP has been blacklisted for some reason.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.